# beautifulsoup 4.4 on python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I am having issues on a new PC and cannot find an answer anywhere.  I am trying to get beautifulsoup 4.4 to work on python 3.5.  I am using pyCharm - I am reading that they may not be compatible but I have the same setup on my laptop and it works perfectly - only difference is the PC I am trying get BS to work on is Windows 7 where my laptop is Windows 8.

When I go into settings and look at Project Interpreter I do see BS 4.4.1 but when I try and run something I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PP/PycharmProjects/Shark/NOCO.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "C:\Users\PP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry
  File "C:\Users\PP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 294, in <module>
    from . import _htmlparser
  File "C:\Users\PP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from html.parser import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not running BeautifulSoup 4.4.1; your traceback shows you have an older version.

In 4.4.1, that section looks like this:

```
try:
    from html.parser import HTMLParseError
except ImportError as e:
    # HTMLParseError is removed in Python 3.5. Since it can never be
    # thrown in 3.5, we can just define our own class as a placeholder.
    class HTMLParseError(Exception):
        pass
```

Line 7 is `try:`. This change was made in 4.4.0, so you have 4.3.2 or older  installed instead.

Upgrade your installed package. PyCharm can do this, or you can use `pip`:

```
python3 -m pip install -U beautifulsoup4
```